# Use the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^4 = \frac15 n^5 + \frac12 n^4 + \frac13 n^3 - \frac{1}{30}n$ to find the value of sup$\{L( f ,Pn) : n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f : [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f (x) := 8−x^4 $ for all $x \in [0,1].$ For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let
$P_n$ denote the partition of $[0,1]$into $n$ subintervals of equal width. Use the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^4 = \frac15 n^5 + \frac12 n^4 + \frac13 n^3 - \frac{1}{30}n$ to find the value of sup$\{L( f ,Pn) : n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$

So far I have let $P_n =\{0, \frac1n , \frac2n , ... , 1\}$ so that we get,

$m_i$ = inf$\{8-x^4: x\in [\frac{i-1}{n} , \frac{i}{n}]\} = 8-(\frac{i-1}{n})^4.$

Using this to obtain that,

$L(F,P_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} m_i (x_i-x_{i-1})$
$=\sum_{i=1}^{n} 8-(\frac{i-1}{n})^4\cdot \frac1n.$

But I dont know how to use this to then sub into the sum that I have been given

Comment: Summation is linear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait: the $m_i$s that you compute are not correct. Indeed
$$m_i = 8-\biggl(\frac{i}{n}\biggr)^4$$
What you are asked to do is to find
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\biggl(8-\frac{i^4}{n^4}\biggr)\frac{1}{n},$$
since the sup turns out to be a limit due to the fact that the the terms of the sum are positive $\forall n\geq 1$. Note that you did not use the parenthesis in the correct way because $1/n$ multiplies the whole $m_i$ and not just the term $(i/n)^4$. Now split your summands to get (applying the formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n k^4$)
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n8 - \frac{1}{n^5}\sum_{i=1}^ni^4 = 8 - \frac{1}{5}- \frac{1}{2n}- \frac{1}{3n^2} + \frac{1}{30n^4}.$$
An easy limit computation leads to the final result, which is $8-1/5 = 39/5$.